# What happened to the older brother (who we never see)?

Tags: plot-explanation, kynodontas

What happened to the older brother (who we never see) in [*Dogtooth/Kynodontas*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1379182/)?

I think that most likely he ran away like his sister attempted to do (by fleeing in the car trunk). It would be consistent with the children leaving upon the sexual awareness of themselves...